# How to get data sent to the server without calling it ?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using jquery-datatables and it works as a charm.
I use it with serverside processing, with global and individual searchs by columns.
I have a button on each table to export data on Excel. My users would like to export filtered and ordered data, I don't know how to get those informations.

Ideally, I would like a function that returns the same [data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) as datatables send to the server when it calls it.

Has somebody any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`ajax.params()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params%28%29)  API method to get the data submitted by DataTables to the server in the last Ajax request.

For example:

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": "/test/0"
 });


$('#btn-get-data').on('click', function(){
    var data = $("#example").DataTable().ajax.params();

    console.log( 'Request:', data );
    console.log( 'Search term: ', data.search.value );
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbem11sw/) for code and demonstration.